# JSTL with Weblogic 12c does not work properly

Tags: jsp, jstl, weblogic12c

I am using Weblogic version 12c and weblogic has in built JSTL support. We just need to set the URI above our JSP. I am using core taglibs using

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

in my jsp. By doing this I am able to use core functionalities like `<c:out>, <c:set>, <c:forEach>` and all. But I can not print my values directly in my jsp. Currently I've to use `<c:out> tag` but I want them printed directly using `$` sign. i.e. `${someObject.someProperty}` - By doing so it prints as it is with dollar sign and curly braces and all, no actual values are printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaking the URI, on JSPs you need to use this:

```java
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Also you can include at the top of your taglibs to allow EL:

```java
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Specially +1 for `isELIgnored`.
Actually my code was working only if I dont put `jsp` in my URI. But in case of putting `jsp` - if I make `isELIgnored false` then it worked...!!!